# How to extract Text from div class banner-text?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

[Image Output Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WF4Hp.png)

please support to extract this text from div class. I'm using the following code but it is not working.

print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='Your object has been successfully created']//p"))).text)

Answer (score 2):

This should work out:

```
var = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.XPATH, "//div[@class='Your object has been successfully created']//p"))).text
print(var)
```

You also could try to just use the class with:

```
var = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
    (By.CLASS_NAME, "banner-text"))).text
print(var)
```